# Creating a countdown but displaying (x-1):00 bug

Tags: java, timer

I've created a timer, which allows to input a seconds and minutes, then begins the countdown, when for example as user inputs 2:01 it becomes 1:00 (instead of 2:00) then 1:59, effectively displaying (x-1):00 of the timer. I know the code doesn't seem very nice to look at and has a bunch of if statements to display a leading zero because integer doesn't like having it.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: How could I go around fixing this bug, I've been looking it for while and I still don't understand how I can go around fixing it.

Comment: Being that this is not a code review, but you should have a look at this for formatting strings
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Specifically "Eight characters in width, with leading zeroes as necessary."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where minutesNum variable comes form. But I would sugess you to only use one int counter variable (very simple to handle) with a display function to display minutes and secondes from that variable.

Comment: I agree. All countdown logic should be done on a single integer that represents seconds. You then create a method that converts that into the format you want.

Comment: This is only part of the code that does the countdown; there's more to the code, shall i post the entire code?

Comment: No need for more code. Use only your counter var (without minutesNum) : `counter--; if(counter >= 1) { display(counter); } else { handleCounterEnd(); }`